# Падает CUDA-ядро

Tags: cuda

Суть задачи такова: в ядре надо перебрать все значения от minor до major, и что-то с ними сделать. Начал с простого ядра:

```
__global__ void testKernel(unsigned __int64 minor_value, unsigned __int64 major_value)
{
    unsigned __int64 current_value = minor_value;
    unsigned __int64 step = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;

    while ((major_value - current_value ) >= step)
    {
        current_value += step;
        // do something with current_value
        step = blockDim.x*gridDim.x;
    }
}
```

Проблема, что данное ядро падает при больших значениях разности major_value - minor_value (точно сказать не могу, но похоже, что при major_value - minor_value > 2^32-1), причем падает вплоть до перезагрузки машины. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Видеокарта GeForce GTX Titan, пишу и отлаживаю через удалённый рабочий стол, на удалённом компе.

Comment: Диапазон значений minor_value >= 0; major_value <= 2^64-1; minor_value < major_value;

Answer (score 1):

Наверняка ваше ядро выполняется слишком долго, драйвер не отвечает и ОС (винда же?) его перезагружает. Иногда не может и оно падает или виснет. Ядро не должно выполняться долго.

Comment: Да, винда. Как быть в таком случае, разбивать диапазон значений и запускать несколько ядер последовательно? Как тогда понять какой подиапазон обрабатывать за один раз, я так понимаю это будет зависеть он конкретной машины.

Comment: @bam Да, бить задачу на более мелкие куски и отдавать уже их ядрам. Иных способов я, увы, не нашел. И размер тоже, увы, придется экспериментально подбирать.

Comment: Немного странно, т.к. на этой видеокарте 2688 ядер CUDA, я запускал на 256 потоках, по идее остальные могли обсуживать нужды ОС, или там не всё так просто?

Comment: Выполнение ядра дольше определенного времени - перезагрузка драйверов если получится. Можете бесконечный цикл в 1 поток попробовать поставить.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Нашёл обсуждение похожей проблемы http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497685/cuda-apps-time-out-fail-after-several-seconds-how-to-work-around-this

Comment: @bam ага, даже ключи реестра упомянуты.